How to fix in Visual Studio C# when trying to view the options for a command in there is a big tooltip window that overlapping the options?
I'm using Visual Studio 2022 v17.11.1 Community edition.
When I type ( to see the options I have, I can use the arrows up/down to move between the options. The problem is the big window that overlapping on it that also show at the same time.
How can I avoid from the big tooltip window to be shown? Or maybe there is another solution?


i found that pressing the Escape key once removing the big tooltip window. but if i will type again it will bring it up again. so it's not a perfect solution but working.

Check your Text Editor toolbar, there are buttons that control how the code-complete popup appears (the buttons may be hidden by default, they'll be in the Expando-arrow on the far right side).

There are two Intellisense options that are both enabled by default. You can turn one off or the other depending on which info you want displayed:
Under /Tools/Options/Text Editor/C#/General then "Statement compilation" turn off either "Auto list members" which removes the large list of parameter member options. (I think the "big tooltip window" you refer to) or "Parameter information" which removes the tooltip with selection of method signatures.

You can disable automatic popup of Intellisense window by this step:
Tools -> Options... -> Text Editor -> C# -> Intellisense -> Uncheck "Show completion list after a character is typed"
Know more about Intellisense in Visual Studio:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-intellisense?view=vs-2022
